# Query changeset components

Tags: change-set

Is there a way to easily query the components in the changeset? Perhaps SOQL? I keep getting validation errors and it's difficult to look through the components by looking at the type, if there was some way to filter and sort the changeset components, it would save a lot of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deploy through package.xml or for deployment through changeset these extensions
[Salesforce Change Set Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-change-set-hel/gdjfanbphogooppaefebaaoohdcigpoi/related)

[Salesforce Change Set Turbo](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-change-set-tur/dlcjllapchpeedkecmhfnpfenpbglioo?hl=en)

**It turns out you can directly retrieve and update changesets directly with the Metadata API.**

**Pro tip:** U can retrieve the contents of a changeset incl. manifest with the packageNames parameter on and it really is that simple.

I made a test changeset in a sandbox with a single component:
[image: Cnageset]

**Note the "Change Set Name" of TestCS.**

Then over to [Salesforce Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) for a migration retrieve(Click on Migration and select retrieve):
[image: Retrival]
[image: Retive]

Complete the Retrieve and download the resulting package zip file:

[image: Final Result]

Extract the zip and check XML where you can find each element in XML as a node. and you can use windows file explorer to search any file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>TestCS</fullName>
    <description>Test Change Set. Updated locally!</description>
    <types>
        <members>OpportunityBatchable</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <version>39.0</version>
</Package>
```

Zip the package back up. In this case it will have the TestCS folder at the root of the zip.

Comment: Not deploy, I just need to analyse the changeset

Comment: see the updated answer here you can retrieve the files included in changeset and you can use file explorer to search any file after extracting the folder As of now I haven't seen any extension to read chnage set elements. This is the reason why we are using various tools to deploy in salesforce like Copado, Ant, ClickDeploy.io etc